# Using Ubuntu as second display wirelessly

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have two ubuntu-running systems:

1. PC: Kubuntu 20.04
2. Laptop: Xubuntu 20.04

The thing is my laptop is not good for doing daily stuff but, it has a great display which I like to use it as a second display to extend my desktop. Recently, I've found something called SpaceDesk that has the required functionallity but, it's only for Windows and Mac. Is there any alternative method or software as simple as this SpaceDesk?

Comment: Try installing Wine by using commands given on there their official website.   https://www.winehq.org/   and then follow their instuction and open Spacedesk windows app by using it @Jab

Comment: Seems the last chance for me. I'll use it if there is nothing like SpaceDesk. By the way thank you.